# High Charts Range Selector

Tags: highcharts

I am using a HighCharts stockChart and have an issue with the range selectors.

When I press on 1 Day, the 1 Month and 3 Months are enabled and can be pressed. When I press on 3 Days or 1 Week, the 1 Month and 3 Months become disabled and cannot be pressed. Pressing on 1 Day makes the 1 Month and 3 Months enabled again.

Has anyone experienced this issue before? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Luke Galea, Could you reproduce that problem in some online code editor? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bnyq1es4/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, perhaps I forgot to mention that this issue occurs only in mobile view. I updated the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q7ny3dv6/
Issue seems to occur in mobile view, however using jsfiddle it is more difficult to test it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That issue is related with `dataGrouping`. As a solution you can set `groupAll` to `true`:

```
series: [{
    dataGrouping: {
        groupAll: true
    },
    ...
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9gs8ukye/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping.groupAll